# Memory RAM consumption (manual)

Tags: windows-10, memory

first question here.

I've searched through some questions but didn't find anything related to my question until now...
I work with Windows 10 Embedded, which is a "flavor" of ordinary Windows 10, made for a specific application. I would like to know if there is official documentation to tell me how much memory RAM each package is consumming. For instance:
Network package (DHCP, TCP/IP, ICMP, etc...) - XXX MB
Audio / Video - XXX MB
And so on
With this information, I will know the minimum footprint to choose the cheapest machine for my application.
Do you have any idea if this manual (or information) exists?? Where can I find it?

Best regards

Comment: Try the [minimum specs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/minimum-hardware-requirements-overview)

Comment: Hi @kicken , tks for your reply. 
Unfortunately, the minimum specs documentation doesn't show what I would like to know. I can't see there how much memory RAM each piece of the Windows consumes... 
I will keep searching 
Tks!!